# I have run into an IndexError: list index out of range, when the line is longer than the index selected

Tags: python

I am looking to iterate through a file to the selected index on each line but I get this error even though there are more variables on the line than the index I've selected.

```
for thing in lines:
    item = thing.split(',')
    **price = item[4]**
    total_Stock_Value = total_Stock_Value + float(price)
print('Total Value of Books in Stock: £{:0,.2f}'.format(total_Stock_Value,'\n'))
```

Comment: why would you do ```thing.split('\n')```, you don't need to split the line by "\n"

Comment: Can we see an example of the lines which you are ingesting/crashing on? Any number of things could be going on here. Thank you

Comment: Could you provide some sample from your data file to reproduce the issue?

Comment: P.G. Wodehouse, Right Ho Jeeves, hb, Penguin, 10.99, 5, fiction,

Comment: You could try something like this to identify the troublesome line: `try` `price = item[4]` `except IndexError:` `print("Problem with line:", item)`.

Answer (score 1):

Check your file for an empty newline(s) at the end, that a common place where this happens. The error will occur for a reason so there must be a line that doesn't have enough comma's.

Comment: Good thought. This is probably it. As long as there are _any_ lines without enough commas, the error will occur some time in the loop.

Comment: Got it, was an empty line in the file. Thanks